# UITableViewCell with TextField on it is not updating upon reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with cells and in each cell is a UITextField. I have these textfields' delegate set to self and doing some calculations upon editing ended.

My problem is with the textfields, whenever I type in a field other than the first one, all my textfields except the first one gets updated. When I type in the first one, the others update perfectly.

This brought me to check what data gets updated and although I set `cell.textLabel.text` equal to the specific position in the array, it does not show the value at that position.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndex` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UITextField *tf;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 25,
                                                           5,
                                                           cell.contentView.frame.size.width/2 - 25 - 25,
                                                           cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 10)];
        tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        tf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        tf.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tf.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        tf.tag = indexPath.row;
        tf.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        tf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        tf.delegate = self;
        tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
        cell.textLabel.text = [_titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tf.placeholder = cell.textLabel.text;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:tf];
    }
    else
    {
        tf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    }

    tf.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue]];
    NSLog(@"Value at index %i is %.2f", indexPath.row, [[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue]);

    cell.textLabel.text = [_titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

When I tried this, after my calculations, this is what was logged:

> Value at index 0 is 1.20
>   Value at index 1 is 1.00
>   Value at index 2 is 4.55

The first textfield however still showed 0 instead of 1.20

Where am I going wrong with adding these textfields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are creating textfield and putting it in same place... So your newer textfield is created on back of previoulsy created one.

You need to check this statement

`UITextField *tf;`

and

```
tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 25, 5,
                                                       cell.contentView.frame.size.width/2 - 25 - 25,
                                                       cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 10)];
```

alloc+init only when previous one is not there. Similar to what you do for `cell`.

EDIT

Check the tags. If i'm not mistaking, the default tag is 0 and thus when using `viewWithTag` it might select the textLabel instead of the textfield. Set the textfield's tag to `indexPath.row + 5`.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code look buggy :

```
tf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
```

Because if you are reusing a TableViewCell, the row won't match.
e.g. The cell get created as row 0 and get reuse at row 10. So `tf` will be nil and won't update.

Each cell is its own little ecosystem, so you don't need different tag in every cell for your textfield. it could just be
`tf.tag = SOME_CONSTANT;`

Also I assume that your are asking the table view to reload it's data.

Comment: I am asking the table view to reload. There is only three rows, so I doubt that the cell is being reused. I am also setting the tag of the textfield because a need to now what row it is in later.

Comment: @LouwHopley when you reload your table the cell ARE reuse. You are just lucky that the system is returning you the reused cell in the same order. In a longer table your code won't work. Like I said it's BUGGY code.

Comment: It will never have more than three lines - it is fixed/permanent data. The tag can not be constant as it is used to identify the row. The code works perfectly now without any glitches or bugs. The only error was that the initial tag was set to 0 which is the same as all the other views on the cell such as textLabel and contentView etc.